# Angular 6 cors Issue can't use a proxy

Tags: angular

Is there any solution to solve angular 6 cors issue ,rather than using a proxy ?

I am already using a proxy , but i'm in a case that i have dynamique url i can't use proxy.
I would like another solution rather than than using a proxy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CORS issue is not about Angular but is a part of [CORS policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)

In order to have it solved the changes should be done on server side, not client. Your server should add appropriate response headers (Access-Control-Allow-Origin, Access-Control-Allow-Methods, ...) and correctly handle preflight requests. See the link above for the details.

Comment: If you don`t have access to the server code or to the backend developer whom you could ask regarding the changes it seems there is no way to solve it besides using proxy server.
There is a small chance that you're sending some forbidden headers and that's why you get a CORS issue but in this case we need to get more details regarding your problem

Answer (score 1):

In most of the cases CORS-Erros are fixed on the server-side.

CORS is defined as the following:

> Cross-origin resource sharing (CORS) is a mechanism that allows
>   restricted resources on a web page to be requested from another domain
>   outside the domain from which the first resource was served.

This definition is from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing). Another soure for information can be [mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS).

IF you cant an .Net API for example you could use change the CORS-policies if your server. Add the following code in your `CongfigureServices`-Method:

```
    // CORS
    services.AddCors(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy(MyAllowSpecificOrigins,
            builder =>
            {
                builder.AllowAnyOrigin();
                builder.AllowAnyHeader();
            });
    });
```

Other technologies should have somithing similar.

If you're using an API not developed by yourself check the documentation of it for further information.

Or as you already mentioned in your question, you could use a proxy.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Fixed on the server side ( symfony 2 ) by adding :

`$response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');`